# How to load a American version of a webpage while browsing through chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-cache

I was in USA for few months and I used to view **hp.com** site to buy laptops. Now i am in India and when i say **hp.com** it translates that into **http://www8.hp.com/in/en/home.html**
Because of that i am not able to see few models which is only available in USA.

So my question is "Is there any way to load the USA page of the site being in India"?

I am using latest version of Chrome browser.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scroll down to the end of the page, and there is a line with two links, your current site , and a link for direct to US version site. goodluck